# Globe 725L Meat Slicer Gearbox Grease

Tags: equipment, maintenance

I have an old Globe 725L meat slicer. The gearbox between the motor and the blade had hardened gross grease in it, and I cleaned it out. I'm putting food grade white grease back in it. Just wanted to confirm that kind of grease is correct, as the other gearbox (on the table motor) had oil in it...like 30W motor oil.

Comment: Sounds right:   https://duckduckgo.com/?q=food+grade+grease&t=fpas&ia=web